# Crash on app launch, possibly related to stored property?

Tags: ios, swift, crash-reports

Some of our users are reporting crashes immediately after launching the app, and we've been digging through crash reports trying to understand the situation. We're currently unable to reproduce the crash.

From the crash report:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
```

and

```
Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   MyApp                           0x000000010012f478 0x1000e8000 + 291960
1   Parse                           0x000000010256dc44 0x102568000 + 23620
2   Bolts                           0x0000000100467b00 0x10045c000 + 47872
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001824754bc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24 (init.c:760)
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018247547c _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:506)
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018247ab84 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1844 (inline_internal.h:1063)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001829e0dd8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12 (CFRunLoop.c:1613)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001829dec40 __CFRunLoopRun + 1628 (CFRunLoop.c:2718)
8   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182908d10 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384 (CFRunLoop.c:2814)
9   GraphicsServices                0x00000001841f0088 GSEventRunModal + 180 (GSEvent.c:2245)
10  UIKit                           0x0000000187bddf70 UIApplicationMain + 204 (UIApplication.m:3772)
11  MyApp                           0x000000010011ebc4 0x1000e8000 + 224196
12  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001824a68b8 start + 4 (start_glue.s:78)
```

Looking at the symbolicated logs, we got that frame 0 to translate to

```
MyViewController.userMarket.materializeForSet (in MyApp) (MyViewController.swift:20)
```

which corresponds to

```
var userMarket: String = ""
```

Is there a reason this might be causing an exception? We're blanking.

Answer (score 0):

Update, in case anyone else runs into this situation: the issue was a bit of a red herring; Apple got back to us and let us know that it was related to a framework that was out-of-date.